# Github Pages не видит стили

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему Github Pages не находит файл стилей?
style.css находится по следующему пути:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам проект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В index.html путь до стилей прописан следующим образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Решетка прописана как %23.

Comment: А сама страница index.html по какому адресу открывается?

Comment: Переименуй `#sourve` в `source` — то есть убери решётку `#` из названия папки и, соответственно путь измени, и попробуй открыть.

Comment: проект new-test. Index.html по пути new-test/index.html